Negative estimates with approximate Bayesian computation using the abc package in R
I am currently using Approximate Bayesian Computation to parameterize uncertain parameters of a model to reproduce observed patterns of disease outbreak presence and absence. To do this, I am using the abc package.
However, when I run the abc function to estimate the posterior distributions of the parameters from neural network regression, I obtain negative values even though all parameters are positive. I don't know if this is related, but I have this warning:
Warning messages:
1: In density.default(x, weights = weights) :
  Selecting bandwidth *not* using 'weights'

Initially, I used the True Skill Statistic (TSS; difference between True Presence Rate and False Presence Rate) as summary statistics (range: -1 to 1), and in a second step, I used the root mean squared error (RMSE) between the simulated TSS and the observed TSS (value of 1) as summary statistics. In both cases, I have negative estimates. So any help would be greatly appreciated to understand what is causing these negative estimates.
Here is the output:
> summary(abc_neuralnet)
Call: 
abc::abc(target = observed_summary_statistics, param = simulated_parameters, 
    sumstat = simulated_summary_statistics, tol = 1, method = "neuralnet")
Data:
 abc.out$adj.values (10000 posterior samples)
Weights:
 abc.out$weights

                               V1         V2         V3         V4         V5         V6         V7         V8         V9        V10        V11        V12        V13        V14        V15        V16
Min.:                     14.0275    -5.5947   475.6561 -2004.7401 -3410.4807    -0.0041    -0.2877    -0.4942    -0.0403    -0.6970    -0.0524    -0.3172    -0.1729    -0.2109     0.4302     0.0319
Weighted 2.5 % Perc.:     21.0431     1.5006   879.1652  2940.7780  -255.8276     0.2331    -0.1156    -0.1222    -0.0179     0.3437     0.0189    -0.1189     0.0248    -0.1586     0.4668     0.0605
Weighted Median:         130.9660    10.4621  5857.8215 18011.2848  2652.1901     0.4609     0.2799     0.5944     0.3044     0.7649     0.5835     0.5960     0.5098     0.5346     0.7495     0.1958
Weighted Mean:           138.2207    10.6428  5880.5932 18186.6218  2798.3743     0.5053     0.2919     0.5823     0.3040     0.7255     0.5612     0.5943     0.5130     0.5410     0.7519     0.1986
Weighted Mode:            41.2750    15.1685  2046.0809  7565.2865   473.4871     0.2850     0.0511     0.6869     0.3914     0.8491     0.9260     0.8935     0.2530     0.4488     0.5668     0.0947
Weighted 97.5 % Perc.:   283.2321    20.3251 10985.0459 34015.6282  6562.8585     0.9261     0.7165     1.2972     0.6245     0.9763     1.0293     1.2934     1.0046     1.2514     1.0480     0.3448
Max.:                    307.9988    20.4851 14114.8565 45242.1735  7852.7231     1.0047     1.1997     1.4287     0.6768     1.0072     1.1691     1.3752     1.0913     1.3801     1.0690     0.4321
                              V17        V18
Min.:                     -0.0444    -0.7655
Weighted 2.5 % Perc.:      0.1018    -0.2778
Weighted Median:           0.5202     0.4043
Weighted Mean:             0.5449     0.4108
Weighted Mode:             0.1790    -0.0694
Weighted 97.5 % Perc.:     1.0907     1.1251
Max.:                      1.2888     2.0197

Here are the data:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/cdse5nhbo60tnv47yjear/Test_abc.csv?rlkey=59umwgnk5juv392te51016t6u&st=924wq05k&dl=0
Here is the code:
library(Metrics)
library(abc)

data <- read.csv("C:/Users/Test_abc.csv")

## Define the observed summary statistics
## observed_TSS <- 1
observed_summary_statistics <- c(RMSE_TSS_C1 = 0, RMSE_TSS_C2 = 0)

## Compute the root mean squared error (RMSE) between simulated and observed variables
data$RMSE_TSS_C1 <- sapply(data$TSS_C1, FUN = function(x){Metrics::rmse(1, x)})
data$RMSE_TSS_C2 <- sapply(data$TSS_C2, FUN = function(x){Metrics::rmse(1, x)})
## summary(data) 

## Retrieve the simulated summary statistics
simulated_summary_statistics <- data[, c("RMSE_TSS_C1", "RMSE_TSS_C2")]
## summary(simulated_summary_statistics)

## Retrieve the simulated parameters
simulated_parameters <- data[, c("V1", "V2", "V3", "V4", "V5", "V6", "V7", "V8", "V9", "V10", "V11", "V12", "V13", "V14", "V15", "V16", "V17", "V18")]
## summary(simulated_parameters)

## Run the "cv4abc" function
cv_rejection <- abc::cv4abc(param = simulated_parameters, sumstat = simulated_summary_statistics, nval = 5, tols = c(0.001, 0.005, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1), method = "rejection", transf = "none")

## Run the "abc" function
abc_neuralnet <- abc::abc(target = observed_summary_statistics, param = simulated_parameters, sumstat = simulated_summary_statistics, tol = 1, method = "neuralnet")


I suggest you produce density plots of the posteriors (and priors if possible). I don't see any negative medians in your output. If negative values are not allowed (i.e., impossible) you usually encode this as a prior with zero propability for negative values in Bayesian analysis. Alternatively, you could use transformations or even reject negative estimates. However, I'm not familiar with ABC.
